# How to update an ember-infinity infinityModel?

Tags: ember.js, infinite-scroll

I am trying to implement searching with ember-infinity.  But, I do not understand the interaction between the route model and infinityModel.

I have the following code:

```
model() {
  ...
  return this.infinityModel("myModel", {...}, {...})
}
```

My search action looks like the following:

```
search(searchCriteria){
  const controller = this.get('controller');
  ...
  _this.infinityModel("myModel", {search:searchCriteria, ...}, {...}).then((myMod)=>{
    ...
    controller.set('model', myModel);
  }); 
}
```

So this works, but the my query gets fired twice when search is called.

The following only fires the query once.

```
search(searchCriteria){
  const _this = this;
  ...
  _this.infinityModel("myModel", {search:searchCriteria, ...}, {...}); 
}
```

But my model does not update.  However infinityModelUpdated() function is fired.  So I assume that means the infiniteModel was updated, which I assume is my model.

I am pretty sure I am missing something simple.  But any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is there any chance you can prepare an ember twiddle to illustrate  your case. I am confused about `search` action. how is that getting triggered? why do you need that separate `search` action?

Comment: Never used twiddle.  Might try to get something up.  However, the search is being triggered by a keyUp action in a component.  It is not a debounce issue on the keyUp action, I checked for that as well.  But I don’t think that is the issue.  I am trying to updated the model with new info.  And while I can do that with the code above, there are two request fired.  And when I just fire `inifinityModel` (without `controller.set('model', myModel)`), there is a callback that says the infinityModel has been updated but my model in my routes does not get updated.

Comment: do you use `infinity-loader` or do you trigger loading only with search criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just calling the following:

```
_this.infinityModel("myModel", {search:searchCriteria, ...}, {...});
```

does not solve your problem; that is because that method call just returns fresh set of new objects retrieved; which is irrelevant with your original model that you had already returned from `model` hook. In other words; that method call makes the remote call but does not push the objects retrieved to the model that is already returned from the hook method. If you instead set the model of the controller; then of course the new data is updated to the screen; but I am not sure why a second remote call is being made. That might be related with existence of an `infinity-loader` already existing in your screen.

What I would suggest is to use `updateInfinityModel` provided instead of setting the model of the controller. Please take a look at the [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/c2ee6043e056c4da6e8133a62f2346c3?openFiles=routes.dummy-route.js%2C&route=%2Fdummy-route) I have provided. It uses [ember-cli-mirage](https://github.com/samselikoff/ember-cli-mirage) to mock data returned by the server. Anyway, our point is looking at the `makeInfinityRemoteCall` action.

```
   this.infinityModel("dummy", { perPage: 12, startingPage: 5}).then((myModel)=>this.updateInfinityModel(myModel));
```

Here a remote call is made upon button click and data is appended to the model already constructed in `model` hook. I hope this helps you clear things. Please do not hesitate to alter the twiddle yourself or ask further questions you have.

After your comment, I have updated the twiddle to change the model directly. The duplicate remote call that you have mentioned does not seem to be appearing. Are you sure an exact duplicate remote call is being made? Can it be just the case you are using `infinity-loader` at your template and a remote call for the next page is being made due to appearance within the view port?

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  While this is helpful, I would like to replace the existing models info, not append it.  I actually tried many variations of updateInfinityModel to no avail before I posted.  I am beginning to think that I may have to live with the extra request.  Also, thanks for the twiddle.  I will use this as a basis for future ember questions.  The use of ember-cli-mirage would have been something that would have taken me much time to even figure out.  Thanks again.

Comment: @user2517182 i have updater the answer regarding your comment? I cannot seem to be having the duplicate remote call, next pages are being requested of course due to `infinity-loader`? i would appreciate it if you can upvote useful answers even if it is not an exact solution that you desire. my best regards.

Comment: I gave you the upvote, since you helped me understand how to use twiddle. :-)  However, there seems to be a build error when I go to the twiddle.

Comment: oh thx. i will look at the error when i got home. sorry for that.

Comment: No prob.  I am appreciative for the help. :-)

Comment: i had mistakenly deleted a paranthesis; fixed that.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.